# Django 1.8 csrf NameError: Undefined

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-1.8

I am using Django_Mako_Plus on top of Django. And as I try to put a `${csrf_input}` after my form. I am getting a `NameError: Undefined`. The middleware is correct. What am I doing wrong? Below is my code:

```
<div class="backgroundregister">
    <form id="registerform" action="/homepage/register" method="post" style="margin-top: -7vh;">${csrf_input}

        <div class="form-group" id="register-id">

            ${ form.as_table() }

            <button style="margin-top:15px; height:40px; width:300px; margin-left:3px; margin-top:30px;" type="submit" class="dissimulation">
        </div>


    </form>

</div>
```

I am using Django 1.8

Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: Django marko plus supports django >= 1.9 , why don't you use django 1.11 instead 1.8?

Comment: @Beomi I believe the update for django 1.9 broke content on 1.8.  It did for my site at least.

Comment: post your settings.py

Comment: did you try ${csrf_input} with spaces like: ${ csrf_input } instead.

Comment: As an update, I did some work and upgraded to 1.9, fixed everything it broke, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @HarshBhikadia Yes, I have tried that.  It makes no difference.

Comment: Could you provide full stack trace?

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but you could try moving `${csrf_input}` to the end of your form `</form>`.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Here is a codepen to the stack trace https://codepen.io/anon/pen/verYyN

Answer (score 1):

> Having downloaded Django-mako-plus 3.8.3 from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mako-plus/3.8.3 and inspected the sources, I found `context_processors.py` to be bare of any definition of a `csrf` function. However, this function is defined in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mako-plus/4.2.6

AFAIK, The middleware doesn't register the context processors for csrf.

Those have to be added to `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your project settings.

For an older version of `django-mako-plus`, create a `context_processors.py` module in your app directory containing this function shamelessly copied from the source:

```
from django.template.backends.utils import csrf_input_lazy, csrf_token_lazy

def csrf(request):
    '''
    Adds the "csrf_input" and "csrf_token" variables to the request.
    Following Django's lead, this processor is included in DMP's
    default context processors list. It does not need to be listed
    in settings.py.
    To include the <input name="csrf".../> control in your forms,
    use ${ csrf_input }.
    '''
    return {
        'csrf_input': csrf_input_lazy(request),
        'csrf_token': csrf_token_lazy(request),
    }
```

Use the location to this module instead in your `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django_mako_plus',
        'BACKEND': 'django_mako_plus.MakoTemplates',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # functions to automatically add variables to the params/context before templates are rendered
            'CONTEXT_PROCESSORS': [
                 ...
                 # adds "settings" dictionary
                'django_mako_plus.context_processors.settings',
                 # adds "csrf" dictionary
                '<appname>.context_processors.csrf',
            ],
```

#### Reference

(django-mako-plus 4.2.6) [django_mako_plus.context_processors.csrf_input](https://github.com/doconix/django-mako-plus/blob/master/django_mako_plus/context_processors.py)

Comment: I already have those added to my context_processors. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What version of django_mako_plus are you running?

Comment: I am running django-mako-plus 3.3.18.0

Comment: Would I just create a new py file with the rest of my views called context_processors.py? Or would I put that in my base.py file?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like your solution worked. I'm just verifying, but if it works, I'll assign the points to you. Thanks a ton!